# Navigation drawer : changing layouts using fragment and adding listeners

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm trying to add the new Navigation drawer to my app and instead of changing images(as they are shown in the google example) I manage to change layouts inside the fragment.

The problem is that after changing a layout I don't have any access to the buttons and other objects inside the layout.

How can I get access to the buttons and other objects that are shown in the current 
inflatered layout, and set listeners?

```
@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{ 
switch(pageNum)
{ 
case 0: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.groups_layout, container, false);
break;
case 1: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.schedule_layout, container, false);
break; 
case 2: rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.courses_layout, container, false);
break;
} 
  theView = rootView; 
  return rootView; 
 } 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: post what you have done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you should do is use multiple fragments and switch between them with the drawer. then just give each fragment a different layout, here's a great example
http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-navigation-drawer-example-using-fragments/

Comment: thank guys:) it works.changing fragments is the better solution in this case than changing layouts inside one fragment.

Answer (score 1):

After changing the layouts, you will still need to reference your buttons in your java class to the buttons in your layout, EVERY time when you change a layout. Then after that setting the click listeners again.

A bit on the tedious side, but that should be the way to do it, judging from the code snippet you've shown.