# Navigation Drawer with Up navigation in ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

Does anyone successfully implemented *Navigation Drawer* with *Fragments*, *Up Navigation* and *ActionBar*?

As stated in documentation *Up Navigation* works automatically with *Activities*. But If I want to implement *Navigation Drawer*, then I have to use fragments.

I have set:

```
   ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
   actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
   actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

I also put all fragments to *BackStack*. When checking listener *OnBackStackChangeListener*, I see that BackStack is being checked, but the Up navigation arrow doesn't show up.

Comment: A navigation drawer generally directs the flow of the app by opening new screens from a main screen.  You want the navigation drawer for every screen?

Comment: Yes, whole application should have access to navigation drawer. If not, I guess I could you other activities that overlaps MainActivity, add there ActionBar with Up button,that when clicked closes this Activity, right?

Answer (score 0):

> Navigation Drawer with Fragments

take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728746/navigation-drawer-changing-layouts-using-fragment-and-adding-listeners) and [this](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer) may also help you. As stated in the second link, you don't "have to use Fragments to use the `NavigationDrawer`"

> *Although many navigation drawer examples show how fragments can be
>   used with the navigation drawer, you can also use a
>   RelativeLayout/LinearLayout if you wish to use the drawer as an
>   overlay to your currently displayed Activity*.

This is actually the approach I've used in one of my recent projects and it works fine.

Comment: I don't understand why using LinearLayout should help in getting work Up Navigation?

Comment: @Tom this was a reply to "using Drawer with Fragments". All I wanted to say is that you don't have to use Fragments to use the the Drawer, I can't tell you why the "back" arrow doesn't appear without seeing your complete code